# How to Get a Notification About the Successful Connected status of both the End Points in Socket?

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets

Q-1)I have to set the "lab2" Visibility true when the connection is established between both the End Points. But when i run the code it is already visible.

@-2) i want to retry the connection if any error occur. But after 5 - 6 times of retrying its showing error [An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll] on the line "main.Owner = this;"

please Help !

```
         public MainWindow()

    {
        InitializeComponent();

        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);      

        connect();

    }

    public void connect()
    {
        try
        {
            epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.10"), 1400);

            sck.Bind(epLocal);


            epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.20"),1500);
            sck.Connect(epRemote);




            buffer = new byte[1500];
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

            lab2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        }
        catch 
        {                
            test();
        }

    }

    private void test()
    {
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        main.Owner = this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:  You should be using the Model-View-View Model (MVVM) pattern for developing WPF applications.  Do a search on MVVWM for information on how the pattern works.

I would create a `bool DependencyProperty` in your view model object called `IsConnected`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsConnectedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register( "IsConnected", typeof( bool ), typeof( MyViewModel ), new PropertyMetadata( false ) );

public bool IsConnected {
    get { return (bool) GetValue( IsConnectedProperty ); }
    set { SetValue( IsConnectedProperty, value ); }
}
```

Next, I would create a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` in the window resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisible" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Next, I'd bind the IsConnected property to the Visibility property of the lab2 control in your window:

```
     Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisible}", Path=IsConnected}"
```

Lastly, I'd modify your connect method so that instead of setting lab2's visibility property, it sets the `IsConnected` property to true if it connects & false if it doesn't.

Regarding your timer, do you really need to keep creating new windows every time you try a connection?  Shouldn't you just create one Window & keep trying to connect?

Comment: Hey Tony m sorry m new to WPF.  m getting error in MyviewModel and PropertyMetaData the type of namespace doesnt exist.

Comment: Visibility="{Binding IsConnected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisible}}" ... and the property of the tab control i changed it to this ?

Comment: Replace "MyViewModel" with whatever the class name of the object into which you're putting the code is.  And the type name is `PropertyMetadata`.  I will correct the spelling in my answer

Comment: Hey tony I am getting and error "A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll"  at the TAB control end. The error is not showing when i build the program. its showing when i run the program ?

Any advice ?

Comment: @Antisan:  In general, you can ignore first chance exceptions.  Those only appear in the Output window of Visual Studio while running in debug mode.  I believe it means that something threw an exception which was caught & handled internally by the framework.  However, if that exception appears on screen while your program is running, it means that your XAML is referring to something that can't be found at run time.  In that case, you need to figure out which line is causing the error & then why it causes the error, then fix it.

Comment: I dropped this idea of using two Enpoints. I am using tcp server and clinet better option :) thankz Tony for the help :)